# iFrame Code shows in footer instead of section

Tags: wordpress, iframe

I am trying to add a code generated from https://pages.etoro.com/widgets/signup/demo.html and the code writes like this

```
    <script>
window['etoro_sign_up_widget_settings']={
    culture:'en-us', // 'en-us', 'fr-fr', 'es-es', 'ru-ru', 'zh-cn', 'it-it', 'ar-ae', 'de-de' , 'pl-pl'
    width:'100%', 
    height:'470px',
    show_uk:false,
    firstlastname:true,
    show_intro:true,
    auto_resize:true, //  auto resize IFRAME, true is default
    social:true, // show social buttons
    container:'.mainContainer', // Container selector (e.g. element name / ID / class)
    affiliate_id:'8906', // Your Affiliate ID
    sub_affiliate_id:'' // Sub Affiliate ID
}</script><script src="https://marketing.etorostatic.com/widgets/signup/signup.js"></script>
```

I tried to place this code inside a section using Code Block in Avada theme WordPress but the code or form that's supposed to be generated from this code does not show, instead, it creates a space in the footer.

Please help what I did wrong.

Comment: Hi, please check your url, that site can’t be reached. Javascript seems ok. We need to reproduce this in order to answer. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @AliKaraca Thank you for assisting me, the URL where I generate the code is https://pages.etoro.com/widgets/signup/demo.html, when I generate the code and paste in the site, it does not show.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it now.

I changed container:'.mainContainer', to a customer CSS ID.